# A little explanation wouldn't go amiss :-)

Tags: javascript

```
  var keyState = [];
  const KEY_UP = 38;
  const KEY_DOWN = 40;
  const KEY_W = 87;
  const KEY_S = 83;


const keyEventLogger =  function (e) {  keyState[e.keyCode] = e.type =='keydown';}
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyEventLogger);
window.addEventListener("keyup", keyEventLogger);
```

Above is a piece of code which I can't take credit for. A user on here posted it in response to someone asking about player movement.Whilst I understand the majority of it (I think) I don't understand one line in Particular. From what I gather:

```
var keyState = [];
```

creates and empty array called Key state

```
const KEY_UP = 38;
const KEY_DOWN = 40;
  const KEY_W = 87;
  const KEY_S = 83;
```

These are just varibles defining what they key code is for certain keys

```
const keyEventLogger =  function (e) {  keyState[e.keyCode] = e.type =='keydown';}
```

This is then the confusing line for me. It is creating a varible called keyeventlogger and then it is equaling it to a function which it is passing e through. That function is then adding the keycode of e to the array and equaling it to e.type (whatever that is) and then setting that to keydown which is the event listener below. Can someone do their best to explain this line of code to me :-)

Much appreciated 
James

Comment: Pendant: The `const` keyword defines a constant and not a variable - by definition!

Comment: It really should be `var keyState = {}`.

Comment: Maybe knowing that the line is functionally equivalent to `function keyEventLogger(e) { const isPressed = e.type == 'keydown'; keyState[e.keyCode] = isPressed; }` might help? Also add a `console.log(e)` to see what events you are getting and what their properties are.

Comment: Please add a link to where you found the code, and the name of the author if possible.

Comment: @Bergi  it doesn't necessarily have to be an object, though it could be. In the example, the author is using the key code as the index into the `keyState` array.

Comment: @JeffKilbride I said it *should* be an object (though arrays are objects and "work" as well). The key codes are not continuous, so they don't fit as array indices.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are first class objects in JavaScript.

They can be assigned to variables, constants, and object properties just like any other value. Likewise they can be passed as arguments to other functions.

Answer (score 0):

`e.type =='keydown'` is an equality test. The result is `true` or `false` depending on whether `e.type` is equal to `keydown`.
It is a boolean value that is then assigned to an element of the `keyState` array.

Basically, when you press a key on your keyboard, it assigns "true" to an element in the array corresponding to that keyboard letter.  When you release the key, the element becomes false.  Game logic will read these elements to determine if the user is *currently* trying to move in a particular direction.

Comment: Thank you this cleared it up for me a little bit :-)

Comment: The code could just have easily been written: 
`window.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {  keyState[e.keyCode] = true; });
window.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {  keyState[e.keyCode] = false; });`

Comment: @ChrisWalsh But that's no fun and looks repetitive :-)

Answer (score 0):

This just creates an array of all keys pressed so far and their current state. `true` if the key is pressed down. `false` if that key is not pressed.

Answer (score 0):

`const keyEventLogger =  function (e) {  keyState[e.keyCode] = e.type =='keydown';}`

This line is assigning an anonymous function to the variable `keyEventLogger`. In javascript, functions are first class objects, so they can be assigned to variables and passed around.

`window.addEventListener("keydown", keyEventLogger);`

Notice that we are passing the `keyEventLogger` variable to the `window.addEventListener` method. What this is saying is -- every time there is a `keydown` event, trigger the `keyEventLogger` function. Now, let's take a look inside that function:

`keyState[e.keyCode] = e.type =='keydown';`

This line is creating (or updating) an entry in the `keyState` array based on the type of key that was pressed. We have assigned event listeners to the `keydown` and `keyup` events, so those are the only two possibilities. Javascript evaluates the `e.type == 'keydown'` part of this line first. If the key pressed equals `keydown`, this will evaluate to `true`, otherwise `false`. So, the value stored in the `keyState` array will be `true` for `keydown` events and `false` for `keyup` events -- with the array index being the key code (40 for `keydown` and 38 for `keyup`).

Hope this helps.